# Different outcomes between Object assign and Object spread

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I am using typescript and compiling to ES2016.
I noticed that I am calling two different functions with similar `this` object in a `Function.prototype.call()`.
I tried to merge both `this` objects by using a common object which would use `...spread` in the beginning of the object like so

```js
let selfShared = {
  props,
  // ...
};

let selfHost = {
  ...selfShared,
  // ...
};

let selfGuest = {
  ...selfShared,
  // ...
};
```

The idea of using the spread in the begging was that I could overwrite the shared properties in either of the `this` objects if I saw it fit.
But unlike when setting `props` straight in the `this` objects using the spread gave out weird results, which turned out to be because `tsc` compiled the code as

```js
let selfShared = {
  props
};

let selfHost = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, selfShared), {
  // ...
});

// ...
```

using my code

```js
let state = undefined;
let attributes = {};
let selfShared = {
  props: attributes
};

let selfHost = {
  ...selfHost,
  get state() {
    console.log("selfHost get state");
    return state;
  },
  set state(originalStates) {
    console.log("selfHost set state");
    !state ? state = originalStates : console.error("`this.states` already defined in the host function.");
  }
}
```

the output looks like

```js
let state = undefined;
let attributes = {};
let selfShared = {
  props: attributes
};

let selfHost = Object.assign(
  Object.assign({}, selfShared), {
  get state() {
    console.log("selfHost get state");
    return state;
  },
  set state(originalStates) {
    console.log("selfHost set state");
    !state ? state = originalStates : console.error("`this.states` already defined in the host function.");
  }
});
```

now at least on firefox 74 to 77 inserting both of the codes into the console and adding

```js
// ...
selfHost.state = {
  thing: "some"
};
selfHost.state = {
  some: "thing"
};
```

throws out different logs...
The precompiled code gives me two of `set state` and an error which are the expected outputs, but the compiled code gives me a `get state` and ignores the rule in `set state` outputting

```
{
  some: "thing"
}
```

instead of the expected

```
{
  thing: "some"
}
```

as in the precompiled code?

Setting the spread into the bottom of the file compiles to

```js
let selfHost = Object.assign({
  get state() {
    console.log("selfHost get state");
    return state;
  },
  set state(originalStates) {
    console.log("selfHost set state");
    !state ? state = originalStates : console.error("`this.states` already defined in the host function.");
  }
}, selfShared);
```

which gives the right output but doesn't allow me to overwrite the properties given by `selfShared`.

Can you explain why this happens with `Object.assign` and if there is a trick to get an output from `tsc` that still lets me do what I originally wanted?

Answer (score 0):

When using spread

```js
let obj = {
  ...otherObj,
  // ...
}
```

or

```js
let obj = Object.assign({}, otherObj, {
  // ...
})
```

The spread is interpreted as literal which means that as in the polyfill the properties are read as strict values, which means that normal values are read normally, setters are ignored and getters are read as normal values.

Setters and getters work as written in the question when the spread is written in the end as

```js
let obj = {
  // ...
  ...otherObj
}
```

or

```
let obj = Object.assign({
  // ...
}, otherObj)
```

since `otherObj` only extends the unique objects.